# Animate a div after scrolling away from the top of the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

I'm currently trying to make a div appear from behind another div after the user scrolls away from the top of the page.

I'm hoping to do this using animate so that it slides out. Like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/xaYTt/99/

But I can't figure out how to make the red box stay behind the blue box until the user scrolls away from the top of the page.

I also need to reverse this when the user scrolls back up to the top of the page, so the red box slides back under the blue box again.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution, but it works nonetheless.

http://jsfiddle.net/37LZ5/

Components:

- Use $(document).scroll as a trigger to know when scrolling
- Use scrollTop() to know how far we're scrolling (0 = top)
- Remember state to make sure animation doesn't get triggered a zillion times (var away)
- Use .stop() to prevent weird behaviour when halfway through one animation, another animation gets triggered

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I'm curious, is the scrollTop () measured in pixels? So if, for example, I changed it to 200 isntead of 0, the animation would start after the user scrolled 200 pixels down the page?

Comment: yes, scrolltop is measured in pixels: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ : "The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area."

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this take a look at this demo

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xaYTt/102/)

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#bottom-box').animate({'margin-top': '200px'}, 1500);
    $('body').hover(function(){
        $('#bottom-box').animate({'margin-top': '200px'}, 1500);
    }, function(){
        $('#bottom-box').animate({'margin-top': '50px'}, 1500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding about your question is correct, this is what you are looking for

Since you said, "User scrolls away from the top of the page", I added a div to be at the top of the page.

```
var isAlreadyOut=false;
$("#divPageTop").mouseover(function(){
 if( isAlreadyOut==true)
 {
    $('#bottom-box').animate({'margin-top': '60px'}, 1500);
    isAlreadyOut=false;
 }
 else
 {
    $('#bottom-box').animate({'margin-top': '200px'}, 1500);
    isAlreadyOut=true;                      
 } 
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle version
http://jsfiddle.net/xaYTt/103/

Answer (score 0):

I did something with jsFiddle that might be what you are after, if I understood your question correctly.

Basically, the red box will animate when you scroll the window more than the distance of the blue box.

Not 100%, just a quick mock up to see if that's what you want.
(When you scroll, click on the scroll bar arrows for more accurate results)

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/xaYTt/104/